# In Rails 3, how do I get the path of a controller's `index` action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my `routes.rb`:

```
get 'contact/index'
```

If it matters, `contact` is a controller with only an `index` method; it does *not* have a corresponding model.

In my layout file:

```
<%= link_to 'Contact', contact_path %>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `contact_path'
```

Do I have to give my route an alias? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Type "rake routes" in the command line and it should show you all the possible variables you can use in "link_to" helper methods. Perhaps it should be "contacts_path". "rake routes" will help you find the right one

Comment: Your missing some information. Are you using resources? If not you need to use match not get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make it a named route. For instance:

```
match 'contact' => 'contact#index', :as => :contact
```

I don't know if you actually want to have "index" in the URL, so I removed it. You also need to map your URL at the corresponding controller & action.

Comment: Adding `:as => :contact` to `get 'contact/index'` worked perfectly, and it allowed me to use `contact_path` when calling `link_to`. Thank you!

Comment: I know this is for rails 3 and older but I came across it and thought I would add what I did for rails 4.  In Rails 4 I was able to do `get 'contact', to: 'contact#index'`. This gave me contact_path.